# Creating a direct link to the top of the comments section of a post

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to code a link that takes the reader directly to the top of the comments section of the relevant blogpost - somewhat like wordpress blogs. I have the following piece of coding entered in blogger.

```
<a class='comment-form' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick' title='comment-form'><img alt='comment-form' border='0' height='25px' src='http:/i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/F698C5CF-D64E-4C9D-B8DA-AC431C5B343E_zpsvpxnfbuv.jpg' width='25px'/></a>
```

This code works fine but ideally I would like the reader to be able to click on a link and be taken directly to the top of the comments section of the blogpost. I have Disqus Comments installed on my blog and although I've tried on various occasions to contact them in regards to the issue I've outlined above, I have yet to receive a reply. Currently this link takes the reader to the top of the blogpost instead of the comments section.

I'd appreciated any help with this matter. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: See ["Deep Linking"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Howto/Create_a_hyperlink#Deep_linking) at MDN.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as selecting the first comment and use a .scrollTo with Jquery

```
$("buttonName").on("click", function() {
   $('body').scrollTo('#fireComment');
}
```

You can address the first comment either by ID, class or :nth-child(1), nth-child is only is each comment has the same class